# Unable to enter value to input box with 'OnKeyPress' attribute - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want my code to enter value in the box below and move to the next page. I'm using selenium in Python to do this.

[image]

This is the HTML for the element.

```html
<input name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a$ctl00$txtPageNumber" type="text" value="260" maxlength="5" 
onchange="return ValidateNumber(this);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a$ctl00$txtPageNumber\',\'\')', 0)" 
onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) 
return false;javascript:return isNumber(event);" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_ctl00_txtPageNumber" 
onpaste="return false;" style="width:60px;">
```

This is my code. How should get this to perform 'onkeypress' function?:

```
for i in range (2,10307):  #looping over the page numbers
       wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_ctl00_txtPageNumber"))).send_keys(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after waiting for the element, since you need only the function onkeypress, try execute script.

```
driver.execute_script("if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;javascript:return isNumber(event);")
```

Comment: What I usually do is whatever the function, I just put it on the execute script, eg. I just copied whatever is on the keypress. I have played it around some time and I have found out that it is also useful to have a javascript code as per below (clicking the radio button to be always true):


driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('someID').checked = true;")

Comment: Got it. Thanks much.